# How to use result of first query in subquery

Tags: mysql, time-series, grafana

I am trying to write a query against a MySQL database for use in a grafana dashboard. I have a working query when I manually select a known timestamp from the table, however when I don't know the timestamp in advance my data is incorrect.

The goal is to get the total amount of UsedSpaceMB across the 4 different Names but only using 1 TimeStmp. i.e WHERE TimeStmp LIKE "%2018-07-27 16%". If multiple TimeStmp's are included across the query then the total amount of UsedpaceMB is incorrect.

Table name is Storage
Fields are TimeStmp, UsedSpaceMB, and Name

```
Select TimeStmp, UsedSpaceMB, Name FROM Storage LIMIT 5;
+---------------------+-------------+------------------------+
| TimeStmp            | UsedSpaceMB | Name                   |
+---------------------+-------------+------------------------+
| 2018-07-27 16:02:07 |    61415607 | Array1                 |
| 2018-07-27 20:02:09 |    61896587 | Array1                 |
| 2018-07-28 00:02:17 |    61767053 | Array1                 |
| 2018-07-28 04:02:04 |    62175704 | Array1                 |
| 2018-07-28 08:02:10 |    62683011 | Array1                 |
+---------------------+-------------+------------------------+

SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM Storage ORDER BY Name ASC;
+------------------------------+
| NAME                         |
+------------------------------+
| Array1                       |
| Array2                       |
| Array3                       |
| Array4                       |
+------------------------------+
```

This query works:

```
 SELECT
 TimeStmp as time,
'Used Capacity' as metric,
(SELECT SUM(UsedSpaceMB) as value)
FROM Storage
WHERE TimeStmp LIKE "%2018-07-27 16:%" AND Name IN ("Array1", "Array2", "Array3", "Array4")
```

(Grafana example where To Time is set to 2018-08-15 04:00)

```
 SELECT
 TimeStmp as time,
'Used Capacity' as metric,
(SELECT SUM(UsedSpaceMB) as value)
FROM Storage
WHERE TimeStmp >= FROM_UNIXTIME($__unixEpochTo(),'%Y-%m-%d %H') AND Name IN ("Array1", "Array2", "Array3", "Array4")
```

What I really want to do first is to select the MAX(TimeStmp) in my original query, and then use that in my WHERE clause so that I'm only searching over 1 specific TimeStmp (i.e WHERE TimeStmp = MAX(TimeStmp) or HAVING TimeStmp = MAX(TimeStmp). I'm not sure how to do the JOIN or use HAVING as when I do this query I get no results.

```
 SELECT
 TimeStmp as time,
'Used Capacity' as metric,
(SELECT SUM(UsedSpaceMB) as value)
FROM Storage
WHERE Name IN ("Array1", "Array2", "Array3", "Array4")
HAVING TimeStmp = MAX(TimeStmp)
```

Expected Result:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(UsedSpaceMB)) FROM Storage WHERE TimeStmp LIKE "%2018-07-27 16:%" AND Name IN('Array1','Array2','Array3','Array4');
+---------------------------+
| (SELECT SUM(UsedSpaceMB)) |
+---------------------------+
|                 777379124 |
+---------------------------+
```

Comment: There would most likely be only a single timestamp with the max value.  What, then, do you mean by wanting to take the sum of the used space?  Can you show us what your desired output looks like?

Comment: The result would return a single timestamp but because there are multiple timestamps across the Names in the table the result total gets aggregated over multiple Timestamps if TimeStmp is not equal to 1 single timestamp. I edited the original question to show results

Comment: `Can you show us what your desired output looks like?`

Comment: Added above, if that's not what you need let me know

Comment: I"m confused.  July 27th is not the latest timestamp, not even for the `Array1` group.  What about the other groups?  If a name does not have the max timestamp, does its used space not get added to the sum?

Comment: The names I provided have a max timestamp and always will. July 27th was just an example.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the sum (presuming there are multiple rows per Name for a timestamp) of the UsedSpaceMB column of rows by Name:

```
SELECT
    a.`Name`,
    a.`TimeStamp` as `time`,
    'Used Capacity' as `metric`,
    SUM(a.`UsedSpaceMB`) as `value`
FROM `Storage` a
JOIN (SELECT MAX(`TimeStamp`) as `tm`,`Name` 
        FROM `Storage` 
        WHERE `Name` IN ("Array1", "Array2", "Array3", "Array4")
    ) b
    ON a.`TimeStamp` = b.`tm` AND a.`Name` = b.`Name`
GROUP BY a.`Name`
ORDER BY a.`Name`
```

Also, not sure why you used `(SELECT SUM(UsedSpaceMB) as value)` when you can just use `SUM(UsedSpaceMB) as value`.

Comment: That presumption is correct. That query gives me an error though:

Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY a.Name
ORDER BY a.NAME' at line 12

Comment: Oops! Left a semi colon in before the GROUP BY. See updated answer

Comment: Also, you should quote column and table names with back-ticks to avoid conflicts with reserved words/function/commands.

Comment: I've been playing with this to figure it out but it doesn't give me the right data. It needs to only pull the UsedSpaceMB for all the mentioned Names for 1 single timestamp row where that timestamp is the MAX(TimeStamp).

Comment: See the update to the query in my answer. I fixed the ON clause of the JOIN

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT SUM(UsedSpaceMB) AS total
FROM
(
    SELECT s1.UsedSpaceMB
    FROM Storage s1
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT Name, MAX(TimeStmp) AS MaxTimeStmp
        FROM Storage
        GROUP BY Name
    ) s2
        ON s1.Name = s2.Name AND s1.TimeStmp = s2.MaxTimeStmp
) t;
```

Comment: Its not, i will try to mess with the queries here and provide more information on what i expect the results to be. thank you though!

Comment: @Ryan You are not doing a good job of communicating here.  _Why_ is my answer wrong?  Does the result from the subquery I have aliased as `t` at least return some of the correct data?